# State not mapped to props react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a simple LoginForm and I try to map the states from redux to react. Here is my code from LoginForm.js:

```
 export class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    render() {

            console.log("**** FORM print store");
            console.log(store.getState());
            console.log("**** FORM print props");
            console.log(this.props);

            if(this.props.loginObj.loginState=='true') { // error here
                console.log('yes');
            }

            return (
            <div><div/>);
            );
          }
      }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    loginObj : state.loginObj
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  doLogin,
  changeText,
});

export default connect(  
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(LoginForm);
```

The reducer contains the property loginObj, if I print the store I see:

```
loginObj:   
    Object { loginState="false",  user="",  password=""}
```

Reducer:

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
    loginObj: loginReducer
});
...
```

However when I try to access the props, it seems that this.props is empty.

> this.props.loginObj.loginState - this.props is null

UPDATE:
LoginForm:

Comment: Show us `LoginForm`.

Comment: Added an update with loginForm

Comment: What does the log `this.props` log?

Comment: Prints: Object {}

Comment: I have main.js-> App.js (here i create the store) -> LoginPage.js -> Loginform.js (here I have connect). should I have connect In app?

Comment: Can I see how you import `LoginForm`?

Comment: import { LoginForm } from './LoginForm';

Comment: so if you log the `state` inside  `mapStateToProps` function, you can actually see the data you want to pass?

Comment: That is weird. I'm going to have to see more of `LoginForm`.

Comment: Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead. also I see this in console. I am not sure if connect is called.

Comment: I updated the post, whith  LoginForm

Answer (score 0):

```
  import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'; //must include


  function mapStateToProps(state){
         return {    
           loginObj : state.loginObj
          }
        }

   function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
       return bindActionCreators({doLogin,changeText},dispatch)
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your correct your `mapStateToProps` method . It doesn't have return value. It shows clearly from the syntax of the method.

Second why are you using `this.props.loginObj.loginState` ? This abstraction level is wrong. As you have mentioned `loginObj` as props, then why you should abstract `loginState` property there? It'll not work.

In redux, you should limit props to same object in the state. For example, if you want todos from state, then mention todos as props. If you want some property of todos, then pass down it to props(for this code) or via children props.

I don't know about your store but, the component should look like:

```
    export class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    render() {

    console.log("**** FORM print store");
    console.log(store.getState());
    console.log("**** FORM print props");
    console.log(this.props);

    if (this.props.loginObj.loginState == 'true') { // error here
      console.log('yes'); 
    }
      // for this issue you could view at this point - 
      // store.getState().loginObj.propertyyouwant only if you have 
      // imported main store in this current file
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
            );
          }
      }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return { loginObj: state.loginObj}    
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>
    {
     return {
      doLogin,
      changeText,}
    };


    export default connect(  
     mapStateToProps,
     mapDispatchToProps,
    )(LoginForm);
```