# mapStateToProps & mapActionsToProps not firing in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component (SearchFilter.js) and am using `connect` to trigger `mapStateToProps` and `mapActionsToProps` on export.

Trouble is, `mapStateToProps` isn't firing -- no props (neither state nor actions) show up in React DevTools and I can't even console log from inside `mapStateToProps`.

I've tried looking at [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58590184/mapstatetoprops-is-not-running) [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51145511/mapping-redux-state-to-props-not-working) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393412/state-not-mapped-to-props-react-redux) but they mostly seem to be typos, or the actions themselves not working.

What's more, I've got an almost identical redux setup for another component (Counter.js) that woks perfectly.

I think it could have something to do with how I provide the store/route to components (see App.js below) as React.Provider shows up in React DevTools for the Counter but not SearchFilter.

Here's the SearchFilter component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addSearchTerm } from "../redux/actions/searchActions";

import "../styles/SearchFilter.css";

export class SearchFilter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchTerm: "",
      showFilters: false,
    };
  }

  //various content...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    search: state.search,
  };
};

const mapActionsToProps = {
  addSearchTerm,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(SearchFilter);
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div className="App">
          <NavBar />
          <Counter />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> // SearchFilter rendered in Home page
            <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

EDIT: Where I've implemented this component in the Home.js view:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>This is the Home page</h4>
      <SearchFilter />
      <ProfilesList />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Show the line where you're importing this component into `Home` ?

Comment: Share your action code, make sure dispatch is used properly...

Comment: Main thing, Until and unless you are not calling your action inside class it will not get executed.

Comment: Edit: @markerikson you and Stijn combined were right! I was importing {SearchFilter} in my Home.js rather than using the default import method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the "export" when you declare the class component, maybe that helps.

change

```
export class SearchFilter extends Component
```

to

```
class SearchFilter extends Component
```

Comment: I did so, and got the following error: "'SearchFilter' is not exported from '../components/SearchFilter'." which is odd, because I still have the export as part of the connect function on the final line of the file.

Comment: How do you import it in the `Home` component?

Comment: Edit: You and markerikson combined were right! I was importing {SearchFilter} in my Home.js rather than using the default import method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using bindActionCreators from redux library - https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators

To dispatch any action from your component, update mapActionsToProps const in your SearchFilter component.

```
const mapActionsToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({
  addSearchTerm},dispatch);
};
```